# Как при выборе элемента в Dropdown'e включать следующий, выключенный, Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Зашел в тупик )

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#pizza").selectmenu({
      disabled: false
    });
    $('#size').selectmenu({
      disabled: true
    });
    $("#sauce").selectmenu({
      disabled: true
    });
  })
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="demo">
    <form action="#">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="pizza">Выберите пиццу</label>
        <select name="pizza" id="pizza" data-type="item1">
          <option disabled selected="selected">Повкуснее</option>
          <option onclick="$('#size').removeAttr(disabled)">Пепперони</option>
          <option onclick="$('#size').selectmenu( disabled , false )">Деревенская</option>
          <option onclick="$('#size').prop('disabled', false)">Гавайская</option>
          <option onclick="$('#size').prop('disabled', false)">Грибная</option>
        </select>
        <label for="size">Размер</label>
        <select name="size" id="size" data-type="item3">
          <option disabled selected>Побольше</option>
          <option value="21">Детская, 21см</option>
          <option value="26">Стандартная, 26см</option>
          <option value="31">Большая, 31см</option>
          <option value="45">Семейная, 45см</option>
        </select>
        <label for="sauce">Чудо соусы</label>
        <select name="sauce" id="sauce" data-type="item3">
          <option disabled selected>Выбирай нехочу</option>
          <option>Сырный</option>
          <option>Кисло-сладкий</option>
          <option>Чесночный</option>
          <option>Барбекю</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="A submit button">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
$('#pizza').on('change', function() {
  $("#size").selectmenu("enable");
});
$('#size').on('change', function() {
  $("#sauce").selectmenu("enable");
});
</script>
```

метод selectmenu принимает значение enable - https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-enable